# Website content not visible in mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on this website http://josedelavega.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch
(Made using this Wordpress theme http://themeforest.net/item/orquidea-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5120180)

On Desktop and tablet everything works great, but not on Smartphones (Samunsg Galaxy S6 in my case). The content looks like "blocked" or "hidden". If you check on Desktop first and than on Smartphone you can see the difference.

There is something wrong into the Media Queries?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
@media (min-width: 980px) {

}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .cs-style-4 figcaption .descrtext {
    display: none!important;
  }
  nav#topmenu {
    display: none;
  }
  nav#mobilenav {
    display: block;
  }
  .serviceslist,
  .teamlist,
  .plicetable {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .singleblog .textblock p {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderarrows .ltar {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderarrows .rgshare {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .leftpart {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 48%;
  }
  .rightpart {
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 48%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .serviceslist .mobiledesc {
    display: block;
  }
  .no-touch .cs-style-4 figure:hover img,
  .cs-style-4 figure.cs-hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .no-touch .cs-style-4 figure:hover figcaption,
  .cs-style-4 figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {

}
@media (max-width: 780px) {
  .blogarchive article.post {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .gallerypage .galleryitems .galitem .imagegally .mask2 .gallydate {
    display: none;
  }
  .contacttop .leftpart {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .contacttop .rightpart {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .abouttwotop .leftpart {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .abouttwotop .rightpart {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .gallerypage .galleryitems .galitem,
  .gallerypage .gallpbd .galitem {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox {
    height: 500px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .rightsidebar,
  .leftsidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  .rightsidebaron,
  .leftsidebaron {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .wrapper .subtitle {
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  #no-more-tables table,
  #no-more-tables thead,
  #no-more-tables tbody,
  #no-more-tables th,
  #no-more-tables td,
  #no-more-tables tr {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  #no-more-tables thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  #no-more-tables tr {
    height: auto;
  }
  #no-more-tables td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */

    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  #no-more-tables td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */

    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */

    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  /*
    Label the data
    */
  #no-more-tables td:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox {
    height: 400px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
  }
  .serviceslist .titleservice {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  header#top .logo {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 130px;
  }
  header#top .headertext {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
  }
  header#top a.gobot {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 65px;
  }
  .teamlist li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px!important;
  }
  .teamlist li {
    max-width: 295px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px!important;
  }
  footer#footer-main p.copy {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: none;
  }
  footer#footer-main div.socialprof {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .blogarchive article.post {
    width: 99%;
    float: none;
  }
  .commentform section.comments {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .commentform section.respond {
    width: 92%;
    float: none;
  }
  .commentform section.comments .scrollbox {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .contactleft,
  .leftpart {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .contactright,
  .rightpart {
    width: 90%;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .teamlist {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  nav#mobilenav select {
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .gallerypage .galleryitems .galitem,
  .gallerypage .gallpbd .galitem {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .opentime .timelineopening li {
    float: none;
  }
  .opentime .timelineopening {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  .serviceslist .titleservice {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox {
    height: 200px;
  }
  .singleblog .slidergallery .sliderbox img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
  }
  .serviceslist .titleservice {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your responsive css file queries it will be look like that:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    //your code

}
```

Just check it. Sometimes its given in theme's options to display content or hide them.

Comment: I just edited the post adding the responsive.css code of my template